# Is there a method to access specific node and relationship data within a graph catalog in neo4j GDS?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

In Neo4j Graph Data Science (GDS), each graph can have a corresponding projection. How can I obtain detailed information about the actual nodes and relationships stored within a specific projection? Is there a method to access specific node and relationship data within a projection?

For a specific graph catalog projection, `graph_0`, I can use `CALL gds.graph.list('graph_0')` to retrieve basic information about the projection, such as the number of nodes and relationships. However, no detailed information about nodes and relations is listed.

------- add an example to explain more detail -----------

1. create a simple graph with following cypher command:

```
CREATE
  (alice:Buyer {name: 'Alice'}),
  (instrumentSeller:Seller {name: 'Instrument Seller'}),
  (bob:Buyer {name: 'Bob'}),
  (carol:Buyer {name: 'Carol'}),
  (alice)-[:PAYS { amount: 1.0}]->(instrumentSeller),
  (alice)-[:PAYS { amount: 2.0}]->(instrumentSeller),
  (alice)-[:PAYS { amount: 3.0}]->(instrumentSeller),
  (alice)-[:PAYS { amount: 4.0}]->(instrumentSeller),
  (alice)-[:PAYS { amount: 5.0}]->(instrumentSeller),
  (alice)-[:PAYS { amount: 6.0}]->(instrumentSeller),

  (bob)-[:PAYS { amount: 3.0}]->(instrumentSeller),
  (bob)-[:PAYS { amount: 4.0}]->(instrumentSeller),
  (carol)-[:PAYS { amount: 5.0}]->(bob),
  (carol)-[:PAYS { amount: 6.0}]->(bob)
```

[example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQIV6.png)

2. project it.

```
MATCH (source)
OPTIONAL MATCH (source)-[r]->(target)
WITH gds.graph.project(
'graph_0',
source,
target,
{
sourceNodeLabels: labels(source),
targetNodeLabels: labels(target),
relationshipType: type(r)
}
) AS g
RETURN g.graphName AS graph, g.nodeCount AS nodes, g.relationshipCount AS rels

// return: 
//graph     nodes   rels
//"graph_0" 4       10
```

3. run a random walk algorithm on the example graph

```
MATCH (start:Buyer {name: 'Alice'})
CALL gds.graph.sample.rwr('mySample', 'graph_0', { samplingRatio: 0.66, startNodes: [id(start)] })
YIELD nodeCount, relationshipCount
RETURN nodeCount, relationshipCount
// return:
// nodeCount    relationshipCount
// 3            8
```

4. In this example, there are multiple relations with the same type between two nodes, e.g. `PAYS` between `Alice` and `Instrument Seller`. I want to know which relationships (identified with relationship ID) are sampled in this sampling process. However, the current provided methods can only figure out which type of relations are sampled, instead of exact relationship IDs.

Comment: Are your trying to get metadata (the schemata), or the actual data?

Comment: In fact, I want to know the relationship IDs within a projection. I've added an example in the question to provide clarification. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, GDS does not provide a way currently (in GDS 2.4.4) to get relationship IDs out of a projection.

But there is a somewhat ugly workaround. You can add to every relationship of interest a special property (say, `_relId`) containing that relationship's native ID. Then you can include that property when creating the projection, and get back that property after you generate your GDS results.

For example, in your use case:

- Add `_relId` to all relationships (since they are all of interest in your use case).

  ```
  MATCH ()-[r]->()
  SET r._relId = ID(r)
  ```
- Project, and include `_relId` property.

  ```
  MATCH (source)
  OPTIONAL MATCH (source)-[r]->(target)
  WITH gds.graph.project(
    'graph_0',
    source,
    target,
    {
      sourceNodeLabels: labels(source),
      targetNodeLabels: labels(target),
      relationshipType: type(r),
      relationshipProperties: r { ._relId }
    }
  ) AS g
  RETURN g.graphName AS graph, g.nodeCount AS nodes, g.relationshipCount AS rels
  ```
- Run random walk.

  ```
  MATCH (start:Buyer {name: 'Alice'})
  CALL gds.graph.sample.rwr('mySample', 'graph_0', { samplingRatio: 0.66, startNodes: [id(start)] })
  YIELD nodeCount, relationshipCount
  RETURN nodeCount, relationshipCount
  ```
- Get relationships from output projection `mySample`, including the native relationship IDs (`relNativeId` in the result).

  ```
  CALL gds.graph.relationshipProperties.stream('mySample', ['_relId'])
  YIELD sourceNodeId, targetNodeId, relationshipType, propertyValue
  RETURN sourceNodeId, targetNodeId, relationshipType, TOINTEGER(propertyValue) AS relNativeId
  ```

Here is a sample result:

```
╒════════════╤════════════╤════════════════╤═══════════╕
│sourceNodeId│targetNodeId│relationshipType│relNativeId│
╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════════╪═══════════╡
│171         │172         │"PAYS"          │256        │
├────────────┼────────────┼────────────────┼───────────┤
│171         │172         │"PAYS"          │253        │
├────────────┼────────────┼────────────────┼───────────┤
│171         │172         │"PAYS"          │257        │
├────────────┼────────────┼────────────────┼───────────┤
│171         │172         │"PAYS"          │255        │
├────────────┼────────────┼────────────────┼───────────┤
│171         │172         │"PAYS"          │258        │
├────────────┼────────────┼────────────────┼───────────┤
│171         │172         │"PAYS"          │254        │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────────┴───────────┘
```

Caveat: If you delete a projected relationship from the DB, then its projection (including its `_relId` value) will be invalid. In fact, the stale `_relId` value would either refer to nothing, or refer to some random new relationship.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although it's not a built-in feature at the moment, it fits my requirements perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can get extended information about a specific native named graph by yielding and returning additional fields like `schemaWithOrientation` from the output of `CALL gds.graph.list()`. For example, `schemaWithOrientation` returns the Node labels, relationship types, relationship orientation and properties contained in the projected graph. You can refer to the full list here: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/graph-list/

Example:

```
CALL gds.graph.list('personsNative')
YIELD graphName, schemaWithOrientation, configuration
RETURN graphName, schemaWithOrientation, configuration.nodeProjection AS nodeProjection
```

Comment: I don't think `configuration` needs to be obtained, as it is not really relevant to question.

Comment: I've added an example to clarify what I want. I don't think schemaWithOrientation is helpful in this scenario, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use inspect the content of nodes by streaming them back (see https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/graph-catalog-node-ops/).
Same works for relationships (see https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/graph-catalog-relationship-ops/).

Further if you are good with Cypher, you can also try out Cypher on GDS (https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/create-cypher-db/).

Comment: Can I write properties back to an existing relationship? As far as I know, procedures like `gds.graph.relationshipProperties` and `gds.graph.relationship` can only create new relationships rather than add properties on existing relationships.